# HTML5 Boilerplate .htaccess vs httpd.conf

Tags: .htaccess, html, httpd.conf, boilerplate

I'd like to start off by saying I am really new to working with apache, so please don't hold it against me.

The HTML5 Boilerplate comes with a .htaccess file, but I'm using django (on webfaction) and so I have a httpd.conf file for apache.  Can I put the code that's in the Boilerplates .htaccess file into my httpd.conf?  I'm confused at the difference between the two and would appreciate any help / insight you can give?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Most/all of the rules in the boilerplate's `.htaccess` can be moved to `httpd.conf`, and in fact this will give a small performance boost, because the `httpd.conf` file only needs to be loaded once by Apache, whereas it needs to read the `.htaccess` on every page load. This of course also means that changes to `httpd.conf` *will* need a daemon restart (`sudo apache2ctl -k graceful` or similar.)

In general, you put things that are relatively "static" in `httpd.conf`, and things that you might want to edit easily and without restarting the Apache daemon, in `.htaccess`. On shared hosts, the customer can typically only use `.htaccess` to modify the server behavior, so in that case that's the only choice you have.